# Delphi XE6 on Windows 7 64bit, FireDAC cannot find libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, delphi, libmysql

I have a little different question from [Delphi XE5 FireDAC Error: Cannot load vendor library libmysql.dll or libmysqld.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857209/delphi-xe5-firedac-error-cannot-load-vendor-library-libmysql-dll-or-libmysqld)

I'm evaluating Delphi XE6 on Windows 7 64bit, I wish to use `FireDAC` to connect to MySQL database.

I have downloaded `libmysql.dll` and install the file in `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\`.

After trying to set `TFDConnection.Active` to `true` during designed time, I got error dialog as displayed below.

[image]

So I tried to use `TFDPyhsMySQLDriverLink`, I have set `TFDPyhsMySQLLink.VendorLib` to `C:\Windows\System32\libmysql.dll`, and set `TFDConnection.DriverName` to point to `TFDPyhsMySQLLink.DriverID` instead, but I got error dialog as displayed below.

[image]

I have tried to place `libmysql.dll` at `C:\Windows\System32\bin` but the error dialog still the same as displayed above.

Please guide me what to do to fix this problem.

Comment: The Delphi IDE is 32-bit and you stored the library into 64-bit system folder.

Comment: Where should I place the libmysql.dll(64bit) to?, I found a comment on other related question mention about `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` so I tried to put the file there too but it was not working.

Comment: The library must be 32-bit. That's what the error message tells you. Try to do [`what Sir Rufo suggests`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857209/delphi-xe5-firedac-error-cannot-load-vendor-library-libmysql-dll-or-libmysqld#comment33089642_21857209).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With carefully reading this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940204/delphi-xe6-on-windows-7-64bit-firedac-cannot-find-libmysql-dll#comment36875170_23940204) and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857209/delphi-xe5-firedac-error-cannot-load-vendor-library-libmysql-dll-or-libmysqld#comment33089642_21857209)

There are a few facts to fix the problem.
- Delphi IDE is a 32 bit application so I need libmysql.dll (32 bit version) instead of 64 bit version.
- libmysql.dll version not depending on the MySQL server itself as I used to misunderstood
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` is equivalent to `C:\Windows\System32` but it's the place to store system dll for the 32 bit Application (like Delphi)

So I've placed the `libmysql.dll` (32 bit version) at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, finally the problem is fixed.

Comment: Just one word about connecting to a database at design time. It's very annoying to open projects that expect to have a working access to some database hardcoded at design-time (left active when saving the project). I would personally avoid connecting to DB at design time completely, or at least write a big sticky note to not forget to turn the `Active` property to False before saving the project when doing so. But maybe it's better these days, I don't know... I still prefer to make all the DB bindings at runtime due to easier maintainability.

Comment: Nice! what about `libmysqld.dll` file?

Answer (score 0):

**xampp**

```
C:\xampp\mysql\lib\libmysql.dll 
C:\xampp\mysql\lib\libmysqld.dll
```

**COPY TO**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\XX.X\bin