# MySQL 5.3 ODBC driver in Delphi XE4

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc

I have installed, registered and tested MySQL 5.3 connector successfully in Windows 7 64 bit.
But Delphi XE4 bind DBX driver for the newly created ODBC connection (there is no way to select a driver from a list). How can I create a new ODBC connection in DXE4 which uses the installed MySQL driver instead of DBX?

I tried to connect via MySQL connector but it can't see it as well. (I have copied the libmysql.dll into windows\system32 from the installed mysql\lib folder)

Comment: If you're using ODBC and have set up a valid ODBC DSN for MySql, DBX doesn't need to know about MySql or its driver - that's the point of using ODBC.  Otoh, i you want to connect to your MySql driver direct from DBX, you can do it, but it won't involve ODBC.  So I think you need to clarify in your q exactly what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @MartynA I want to connect to mysql db but i can't. The connection works in Win control panel but DXE4 unable to connect either with ODBC nor with MySQL connector.

Comment: You should not be copying files into system32. Remove that file.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940204/delphi-xe6-on-windows-7-64bit-firedac-cannot-find-libmysql-dll?